# Show that for the harmonic wave equations, $A^2 = B^2 + C^2, \cos(\phi) = \frac{B}{A}, and \sin(\phi) =\frac{ C}{A}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A harmonic wave can be expressed with the equation $\psi(x,t)=A\cos(kx+ ωt + \phi)$. It can also be written as $\psi(x,t)=B\cos(kx+ ωt) - C\sin(kx+ ωt)$.

How can we show that, for the same harmonic wave, we will have

${A}^{2} = {B}^{2} + {C}^{2}$; 
$\mathrm{cos}(\phi) = \frac{B}{A}, \mathrm{sin}(\phi) = \frac{C}{A}$

I started with setting $A\mathrm{cos}(kx+ ωt + \phi) = B\mathrm{cos}(kx+ ωt) - C\mathrm{sin}(kx+ ωt)$ and have been trying relentlessly to manipulate it from there, but I can't seem to make any progress.

I've managed to boil it down to ${A}^{2} = {B}^{2} + C^2\tan^2(kx+ ωt) - 2BC\tan(kx+ ωt)$ by squaring both sides and dividing through by ${\cos}^{2}$....which is close to that first relation but I've hit a wall.

Comment: This is just about maths, not Physics. Just express $\cos(kx + \omega t + \phi)$ as $\cos(\alpha + \phi)$.

Comment: Vote to close as a maths question, no physics involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain this is by considering the formula for the cosine of a sum: $$\mathrm{cos}\left(\alpha +\beta \right)=\mathrm{cos}\alpha \mathrm{cos}\beta -\mathrm{sin}\alpha \mathrm{sin}\beta $$
Substituting $\alpha=kx+\omega t$ and $\beta=\phi$ gives us (along with multiplying by A): $$A\mathrm{cos}\left(kx+\omega t + \phi\right)=A\mathrm{cos}( kx+\omega t) \mathrm{cos}\phi -A\mathrm{sin}(kx+\omega t) \mathrm{sin}\phi $$
Notice that $\mathrm{cos}(\phi)=\frac{B}{A}$ and $\mathrm{sin}(\phi)=\frac{C}{A}$.

We know that the pythagorean theorem works for any $\phi$, i.e. $\mathrm{{cos}^{2}}(\phi)+\mathrm{{sin}^{2}}(\phi)=1$. The result follows from combining those two statements.

*Nota bene:* This is really just a math question, the point is that you try to use trigonometry to understand wave motion.

Comment: Good for you on the answer and the math jax edit slog, neither of us spotted the title through:)

Comment: I didn't notice it at all until now, lol